# Web based filters for Kafka Consumer

Tags: spring-kafka

We currently have a spring-based web application that has a bunch of filters that do authentication and data addition etc. We are looking into Event based systems with Spring-kafka as the implementation, and hence the current filters cannot be invoked in the event based approach. Now is there a transport-agnostic way of achieving the same. Is there a way/approach which I can use for both the Web based requests and Event based, that exactly mimics what a filter can do for Web requests. I'm aware that Spring Kafka provides a RecordInterceptor interface, but I cannot use this in a Web based request.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to put the code in a common class and call it from both the record interceptor and web filter.

There is no common API available.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Even I was thinking on similar lines.